# Why is my html page not downloading these files?

Tags: html, download

```html
<a href="/text-file.txt" target="_blank" download="text-file.txt"><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>
```

This is my code. My browser is updated to the correct version to be able to run the download attribute in html. Instead of downloading the file, it opens the file in a new tab as a local file.

Comment: try without target="_blank"

Comment: Same thing sadly

Comment: it works fine for images... txt on my macbook does the same as you are saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because you opened the HTML file by double clicking it. You have to run a server serving your file and it should work then.

Comment: This seems to be the answer to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Where is this file located at? I mean, what is the path of it?
try it this way:

```
<a href="text-file.txt" target="_blank" download><button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button></a>
```